# Hashed Passwords in ActiveMQ Classic?

Tags: activemq-classic

We are currently using ActiveMQ 5 with the `SimpleAuthenticationPlugin` and encrypted passwords in property files. In the future, we want to use password hashes instead of encrypted passwords in our property files. Is there an easy, out-of-the-box way to do this? Preferably one that does not involve writing custom plugins, using 3rd party components or switching to another broker, e.g. ActiveMQ Artemis?

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. There is no easy, out-of-the-box way to use password hashes instead of encrypted passwords in your property files.

The underlying use-cases for encrypting passwords vs. hashing are different. Encrypting passwords holds open the possibility that they may be *de*crypted. This is useful for situations where a middle-man (e.g. the broker) needs to use the password to access an external system (e.g. a database). Hashing passwords eliminates the possibility of decryption and is only useful for comparisons (e.g. comparing the hash of an incoming passwords against an existing hash).

The [password security functionality in ActiveMQ 5.x](https://activemq.apache.org/encrypted-passwords) makes no distinction between these use-cases. Everything is encrypted and decrypted the same way and passed through to the underlying components (e.g. the security plugin).

Furthermore, the [`SimpleAuthenticationBroker`](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-broker/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/security/SimpleAuthenticationBroker.java) makes a *simple* comparison (as the name suggests) between the incoming password and the password recorded in the configuration without any consideration that the recorded password is hashed.

To get around this limitation you'd need to implement your own security plugin and hashing functions (since the built-in `encrypt` command won't suffice).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Our motivation is a requirement that prohibits decryptable secrets in the file system. Implementing our own security plugin would be a viable option. However ... while further investigating the situation I stumbled upon the ´ShiroPlugin`. Wouldn't this also allow us to use hashed passwords without having to implement/maintain a custom plugin?